# How could I redefine or change the value of a predefined parameter in Dymola during the simulation?

Tags: modelica, dymola

I am building model in Dymola. I have defined the mass of this model as a parameter, because it would be transfered into other moduls and called in them.  But the mass should be changing during the simulation in different time intervals. For example, during the first 100 seconds the mass should remain 500kg, and during 100 to 200 sec, a passenger is going to get in, so that a new mass should be calculated including the mass of the passenger. But it has been showed, that "The problem is structurally singular", because to the parameter values have been twice assigned. Could someone give some tips to solve this problem? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

If you define the mass of your component as an `input` rather than a `parameter` then you can change it during simulation by assigning e.g. the output from a `TimeTable` to it. For example

```
model Component
  input Modelica.SIunits.Mass mass "Passenger dependent mass";
equation
...
end Component;

model systemModel
  TimeTable timeTable;
  Component component(mass=timeTable.y);
  OtherComponent otherComponent(mass=component.mass);
equation
  ...
end systemModel;
```

Note that the other components using the mass must also have their internal mass 'parameters' defined as `input` to allow higher variability than parameters.

Best regards
Rene Just Nielsen

Comment: Thank u very much for your advice. I have a further question about this solution. It is no problem to set all the mass in other moduls as input. But in one modul I have to use the mass in a limiter, limiter.umax can just accept parameters or constants. Must I build a new own modul as a substitution for the limiter? Or can I continue using a limiter-block? Thanks a lot

Comment: Yes, you will have to use another type of limiter. E.g. `Modelica.Blocks.Nonlinear.VariableLimiter` in which `uMax` and `uMin` are replaced with inputs.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have almost approached my aim. Sorry, but I think I still have the last question for my modelling. I have used directly a bodyShape (from MultiBody in Mechanics), the definition of m is a parameter. Do you have please a suggestion for this problem? Many thanks for your helpful tips and wish u a nice day.

Comment: Fortunately, `m` is defined directly in `BodyShape` and not in some base class of `BodyShape`. You should simply make a copy of `BodyShape` in your own library and redefine `m` as an `input` instead of a `parameter`.

Answer (score 3):

Modelica parameters are defined by the fact, that they don't change over time. Therefore you would need to stop the simulation, change the parameter and restart the simulation (see another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58855130/how-can-i-continue-simulating-a-motion-with-changing-parameters-in-dymola/58855895#58855895)). Given you description I would rather not use this possibility, as it seems your variable is designed to change over time.

A better alternative seems to be defining the mass as a variable. If this is done, you can:

1. Transfer this variable from one model to the others using interfaces. This could be a bit tedious depending on the amount of classes using the variable.
2. Use `inner`/`outer` (basically global variables) is a feasible concept for this use-case. This concept is used in the MultiBody libraries `world` model.

With both solutions you will have to modify the original mass model, as `m` would then have to be a variable instead of a mass.

Comment: I will have a try, thank u very much for the helpful tips.